# Okami Drawing Mechanic in Monogame

Tags: joystick, hand-drawn

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about using the drawing mechanic of Okami in my own game. Basically I want to be able to track joystick movement in a closed region, and have it appear on the screen like Okami.

Comment: Are you asking how to design your game around the mechanic?  That would be difficult to answer for anyone except you.

Comment: Sorry for not being more explicit in my question. I was actually hoping to understand the underlying programming behind getting such a mechanic to work. I was hoping for some documentation on how I can track joystick movement. How I could draw on the screen, based on the joystick movement?

Comment: Have you already made an attempt?  There are lots of substeps, but the first one would be to do _anything_ with a joystick.  If you haven't already, google is the correct way to learn how to do that.  This stackexchange does not offer tutorials or get-started guides.  You should make an attempt to read joystick input, and come back with specific issues related to your implementation.  Also, read [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Have an array of positions.
2. Each frame, read the joystick's position and write it into the array, after the position from the previous frame.
3. Each frame, draw lines between the positions you recorded in the array.